# Dealing with int arrays in c++ 2

Tags: c++, cout

Hi guys could anyone explain why does this program correctly even being a bit     starnge:

```
int main()
{

int array[7]={5,7,57,77,55,2,1};

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   cout<<i[array]<<", "; //array[i]
cout<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

why does the program compile correctly??

Comment: Some compilers will detect obvious logic errors in you code, but that is not their main job.  Your example could be caught by a compiler, but it is up to each compiler what they look for.

Comment: If you use std::vector<int>, the debugger should warn you when accessing out of bounds.

Answer (score 6):

An expression (involving fundamental types) such as this:

```
x[y]
```

is converted at compile time to this:

```
*(x + y)
```

`x + y` is the same as `y + x`

Therefore: `*(x + y)` is the same as `*(y + x)`

Therefore: `x[y]` is the same as `y[x]`

Comment: ok but x is const char pointer to the first element of the array so how xoulsd we sum an integer 'y' and pointer to char 'x'??

Comment: When you add an integer (say: **N**) to a pointer (say: **P**), you get a pointer that points to the element that is **N** elements away from what **P** points to.

Answer (score 1):

In your program, you are trying to index an array out of its bounds. This will probably lead to a **Segmentation Violation** error, meaning that in your program, there is an attempt from the CPU to access memory that can not be physically addressed (think that it is not allocated for the array, as it is out of its bounds). This error is a runtime error, meaning that it is not in the responsibility of the compiler to check it but will it will be raised from the Operating System, having become notified by the hardware. Compiler's 'error' responsibilities are lexical and syntactical errors checking, in order to compile correctly your code into machine code and finally, binary.

For more information about Segmentation Violation error or *Segmentation Fault*, as commonly known, look here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault

Answer (score 0):

You've come across **Undefined Behavior**. This means that the compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants with your program -- including compiling it without warnings or errors. Furthermore, it can produce any code it wants to for the case of undefined behavior, including assuming that it does not occur (a common optimization). Accessing an array out-of-bounds is an example of undefined behavior. Signed integer overflow, data races, and invalid pointer creation/use are others.

Theoretically, the compiler could emit code that invoked the shell and performed rm -rf /* (delete every file you have permission to delete)! Of course, no reasonable compiler would do this, but you get the idea.

Simply put, a program with undefined behavior is not a valid C++ program. This is true for the entirety of the program, not just after the undefined behavior. A compiler would have been perfectly free to compile your program to a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Benjamin Lindley, Compile the below code and you will see how the address are calculated:

```
int main()
{

int array[7]={5,7,57,77,55,2,1};

cout<<&(array[0])<<endl;
cout<<&(array[1])<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

output:(for me);-)
0x28ff20
0x28ff24

Its just &(array+0) and &(array+1)..